How can I use abs in gurobipy & pyomo?
I have objective function like this:
    def obj_expression(m):
        return sum(sum((m.xr[i,j] - m.x[i, j]) + m.gamma * abs(m.v[i, j] - m.v0[i, j]) 
                    for j in m.J if m.xr[i,j] != 0) 
                for i in m.I)

    #Assigning objective function
    model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_expression)

abs() couldn't work. I tried gp.abs_(), it is not worked. I tried to multiply with square and then multiply with square root. It didn't work.
I wanted to define "m.v[i, j] - m.v0[i, j]" as variable and give restrictions/constraints like "should be bigger than 0", but I couldn't write the code with pyomo language.
Could you help me about this topic ?

Does this answer your question? How to make integer optimization with absolute values or sum of absolute values in python?

I know but I couldn't write m.v[i, j] - m.v0[i, j] as variable because of it depends to i and j.

It is an indexed variable.... the second part of the answer I linked covered how to do this for an indexed variable.

You really should post more of your code... minimally showing what all of the elements are in the code.
I'll assume m.v and m.v0 are both variables, not params/constants.
So to capture the abs(m.v - m.v0) where both are indexed by (i, j) you can just introduce a companion variable indexed by the same indices and then constrain it to be greater than the pos/neg values as shown in the linked answer...
m.v_abs[i, j] as a variable indexed similar to v

then 2 constraints, both for each i, j
m.v_abs >= m.v - m.v0

m.v_abs >= -(m.v -m.v0)


Note: this is only valid if the objective is being minimized.
